# Sharepoint - How to Generate a Scripting Error in Outlook for Test

Tags: javascript, testing, sharepoint, outlook

**Hello,**

**I am trying to test error supression on Sharepoint but I am having some trouble.**

**This is my process:**

On a relatively plain website (all it contains is a colored-in div), I added this script:

```
<script>
        var x[] = 0;
        var err = 10/x;
       alert(err);
   </script>
```

When setting my Outlook homepage to this site, I see this error:

[image]

I also have the following script, which suppresses this message (when adding this to my code, the error message doesn't appear):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onerror = function(message, url, lineNumber) {  
        // code to execute on an error  
        return true; // prevents browser error messages  
    };
    </script>
```

I want to test this script out on my Sharepoint site, but when I embed the above, error-inducing code onto my Sharepoint homepage and open the page in Outlook, I am not seeing any error messages.

I added the code in the following ways:

```
1 - Page > Edit > Edit Source > Added the code to the top
2 - Page > Edit > Embed Code > Added the code to various areas of the page
```

**Neither of these methods worked, and the first one actually produced a message** **telling me that I should use the embed function, which also doesn't seem to work!**

**I need to generate this error from the Sharepoint page so that I can check **whether the error-suppressing script actually does what it's supposed to. Can **anyone think of what may be going wrong here?**

**Any help is much appreciated!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is apparently a [known issue in Sharepoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/104849/javascript-works-when-on-edit-page-but-not-when-page-is-published), and can be resolved by using the following function:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function(){

    //your code goes here...

});
```

For the purposes of the above test, I was able to generate an error with the following:

```
<script language='javascript'>
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function(){
        var x[] = 0;
        var err = 10/x;
        alert(err);
    });
</script>
```

And adding the below suppressed the errors:

```
<script language='javascript'>
    window.onerror = function(message, url, lineNumber) {  
        return true; 
    };
 </script>
```

Note that this only worked for me after adding the 2 bits of code in their own, seperate `<script>` tags. I also had to add `language='javascript'` to the tags before it would work.

I added the code by **embedding** some new code, and adding both of the script tags to that web part. Because I was able to produce the error message, I was also able to prove that the error-suppression method worked.