# How to Prevent Authentication for Specific Sharepoint Page

Tags: javascript, authentication, permissions, outlook, sharepoint-2013

I would like to set our user's Microsoft Outlook Home Page to point to our intranet news page(hosted on Sharepoint).

I finally managed to suppress some JS errors I was getting when trying this ([See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33955822/sharepoint-how-to-generate-a-scripting-error-in-outlook-for-test)).

However, when users access this homepage through outlook, they are asked to provide their Sharepoint credentials. They are then not required to do so for the next 24 hours. The next morning, they will be asked to provide credentials again.

Is anyone aware of a way around this, perhaps by embedding a script into the page or by setting some specific page permissions? Usually, the user can access the site without having to log in if they navigate via IE, so why does this not carry over to the Outlook web browser?

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.
Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to solve this problem  I changed my approach completely.

Instead of linking to the web page directly in Outlook I created scheduled task which queries the SharePoint server for the news article data, and then builds an HTML page with the 10 latest articles.

This task runs hourly and the HTML file is linked to on each user's Outlook homepage.

If anyone would like to see the code I use to achieve this please efelf ree to message me.

Answer (score 1):

Have you push down the GPO Settings for IE Settings - Trusted Intranet Zone?

Another way is to turn on Anonymous Access to your portal. See [link](https://support.cloudshare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200701115-How-to-Enable-Anonymous-Access-to-a-SharePoint-2013-site)

Comment: hi Ah Cheng, I have tried setting the GPO settings, but this doesn't seem to work. I think this may have something to do with the fact that users are connected via thin clients over Citrix. We also do not wish to allow anonymous access. Currently the best idea is to try and scrape the SP data and recreate the page every time it is updated, thereby allowing users to access the flat HTML+CSS page from their machines